# AppPools hang in IIS8

Tags: windows-server-2012, web-hosting, application-pools, iis-8

I am running IIS 8 on a windows server 2012 box with 32 gigs of ram.  I have about 50 pools that are all pointing at the same source code for a CMS.  These pools are broken down to aprox 10 sites per pool. Everything is currently configured to the default IIS settings using .net 4.0 integrated pools.

I am experiencing app pools hanging. This does NOT bring the pool down or any of the sites in IIS. It just hangs. Nothing gets served to the page all you see is the the page spinning(loading). I have seen it go on for maybe a half hour or more. I usually stop if it last any longer then that. No Timeouts pop up or any server errors. I have to move the sites out of that pool in order to get them back up. Manually stopping or recycling the pool does nothing.   Even if I stop and start the pool/site there is no effect. The server's ram stays a little high ranging from 70% to 90% when i check it. MS SQL server is also running on this box so that can soak up a lot of ram as well. I am wondering if I need to change some configurations in IIS to optimize it for the hosting that i have to do on this box.

Does anyone have any insight or experience with this issue? Is there any recommendations as to what i could optimize to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Check your HTTP.sys Error Log (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\). If you are stopping the application pool the site is using the site should stop spinning and show Service Unavailable. Otherwise, check Resource Monitor, specifically looking at disk queue as you may too many requests for the shared files.

Comment: @BrockHensley This directory does not exist on my box.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing on IIS8.5/Win2012R2. There are no log entries in HTTPERR associated with it. The Worker Processes view shows that the app pool isn't running when the problem shows itself, and an appPool start/stop will not bring the appPool back up. I've seen this both with AlwaysRunning & OnDemand appPools.